# Good way to write sub queries in pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Incase I have to execute more queries in a single API in what method I have to proceed
Is this a better way to write sub queries inside main queries
without using db.task or db.tx or else I have to use these methods.
like this below

```
function userChangePassword(req, res) {
    const changePwd = req.swagger.params.body.value;

    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    token.replace('Bearer ', '');
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    const newpass = changePwd.newPassword;
    const user_id = decoded.userId;

    const userSel = `select * from xx."yy" where "userId" = '${user_id}' AND "status" = 1`;
    const updatePwd = `update xx."yy" set "password" = '${newpass}' where "userId" = '${user_id}' `;

    db.query(userSel).then((usrResult) => {
            if (usrResult.length > 0) {
                db.query(updatePwd).then(() => {
                    res.send(response.success("The password has been changed successfully", []));
                });
            } else {
                res.send(response.success("The password has not changed successfully", []));
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (util.isError(err)) res.error('NotFoundError', err); // return 404
            else res.error('InternalServerError', err); // else 500
        });
}
```

kindly help me to get solution for this confusion..
Thanks.

Comment: Why won't you just use the mentioned `task` and `tx` methods? See [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I have used task and tx but my question is which one is good approach and give better performance in query execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dependency between queries, then you have to use methods `task`/`tx`. Otherwise, you can concatenate queries into one, using [helpers.concat](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.concat), and execute them as one query, which will be faster. And you can use methods [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) / [multiResult](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multiResult), if you are expecting return data from your multi-query.